# Delete all Ubuntu themed things and install default Adwaita for everything?

Tags: themes

I dislilke the default Ubuntu theme.
I dont like the GTK3=4 Theme. I dont like the shell theme. I dont like the icon theme.

Is it possible to rip all of that out and replace it with the **new** Adwaita theme?
I highlight new because there is for example an Adwaita icon theme installed but those are still the old brown icons.

I know https://github.com/lassekongo83/adw-gtk3 exists. But this ist just for gtk3 themes and doesn't change GTK4 or Shell themes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not as dramatic as you describe it. Nothing must be "ripped" out. If you do not like the theme, then install one that you like. That is the reason why people write themes.

The link you provided does the opposite of what you want to achieve: It is a gnome3 theme that mimics the libadwaita settings, which are used for GTK4. So it renders the GTK3 applications to the look that you want to get rid of.

Browse through [pling](https://www.pling.com/browse?cat=135&ord=latest) and download the theme that you like best.Most of them support GTK3 and GTK4. Some of them have an integrated approach and offer a GnomeShell in addition ([myTheme](https://www.pling.com/p/1424967/) for example). The gnome shell settings have to be tweaked with addons.

**Spoiler:**

Some of your apps won't accept any new theme, since they're snap apps.

Comment: Thank you, but after some more research I found this: sudo apt install gnome-session. Which does exactly what I wanted.